# Error Microsoft Graph API. Get Messages for Channel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, azure-api-apps

my program through a Graph API call accesses channel messages. I have a problem. For one Azure application it works but for another it doesn't.
The two applications have the same Api authorization. What can it be?

> var c = Task.Run(() =>
> graphClient.Teams[teams].Channels[channelId].Messages
> .Request()
> .GetAsync());

It's the error:

```
Code: UnknownError
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2020-08-28T12:15:04
    request-id: 3026d5b8-8178-45f0-97a2-103d5a602b33
ClientRequestId: 3026d5b8-8178-45f0-97a2-103d5a602b33
```

It's Api authorization

[image]

Comment: Please provide the detailed error message. What is the error code? 401 or 403? And What auth flow are you using?

Comment: i'm using this code for auth:
`IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(AppIdAzure)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithTenantId(tenantID)
                .WithClientSecret(AppSecretAzure) 
                .Build();

            IAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);`

The error is Forbbiden: 403

Answer (score 1):

[List channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) is included in [Protected APIs in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).

To request access to these protected APIs, complete the following [request form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtUQ1VJMlNTNUdJV1FKTzVZSVU4MlMwTTdOTSQlQCN0PWcu).

The form requires you to enter the "App id(s) to enable application permissions for".

After that the 403 error will be fixed.

Comment: I filled out the form a few minutes ago. Do you know how long it takes for the problem to go away?

Comment: @ruosco82 Not sure about it. But it shows "We review access requests weekly. If you would like to provide information in addition to the form, you can contact teamsAppPerms@microsoft.com." Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: Hi @Allen,
it's been a week since I filled out the forum but I still have the same problem.
Did I also write an email but without result?
Other ideas?

Comment: @ruosco82 Sorry I have no idea. But I guess that team may be experiencing high workload. You need to wait more time.